# will parsley js working for elements coming at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to use parsley js for validations. But some of our forms coming as templates at runtime. They are mustache templates.

So does parsley work for elements which come later?

```
<form id="loginfrm"  data-validate="parsley">

                    <input type="text" name="login" id="loginEmail" 
                        data-required="true" data-required-message="login required" 
                        data-type="email" data-type-email-message="test"
                        placeholder="test" />

</form>
```

after that i am using as below which is not working , the below one always returns true

```
$('#loginfrm').parsley().validate() == true
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use 1.x `data-` attribute tags in your HTML, while you are using 2.x javascript validation API.

Which parsley version do you run? If its 2.x.x, you'll have to use `data-parsley-` DOM attributes. Please look at the doc here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-data-attrs

Best